# Is there any way i can add sno to a file using openfile?

Tags: python

## I want to add a serial no every time a new user information gets appended in.

```
def get_info():
    op = open('sign in info win.txt', 'a')
```

## serialno here is written to show where i want to add sno.

## this piece of code is non working

```
    op.write('information-no - ' + serialno + '    Name = ' + enter_name.get() + '    Password = ' + enter_password.get() + '\n')
    op.close()
    message = messagebox
    message.showwarning(title='Saved !', message='Information Saved.')
```

Comment: This code seems like it will do what you want.  Are you having some problem?

Comment: Where is *serialno* defined? What (if anything) causes it to be changed? Also, it looks as though *enter_name()* might be a function that takes user input. If so, adding calls to it in a string concatenation is IMHO very poor style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question should already do the job, so if you're looking for a way to create a serial number perhaps you could use `random`.

```py
import random

def generate_serial(length=10):
    characters = list(range(0, 9))
    serial = ''
    for c in range(length):
        serial += str( random.choice(characters) )
    return serial

# Your existing code
def get_info():
    serialno = generate_serial() # generate a new serialno each time
    op = open('sign in info win.txt', 'a')
    op.write('information-no - ' + serialno + '    Name = ' + enter_name.get() + '    Password = ' + enter_password.get() + '\n')
    op.close()
    message = messagebox
    message.showwarning(title='Saved !', message='Information Saved.')
```

Here's a sample of what sort of serial numbers this would produce:

```py
'5570344311'
'3852070084'
'5115012613'
'1655833704'
'6875243550'
```

Please note that while unlikely, it's entirely possible that generate_serial() will produce the same serial number for more than one user. Longer serial numbers or ones that can also contain letters reduce this probability, but if you want unique serials for every user this is not the way to go!

Comment: Your generate_serial function could be much simpler. e.g., *return random.randint(10 \*\* (length - 1), 10 \*\* length - 1)*

Comment: That's a clever approach, but would you agree that it's a little harder to get your head around as a beginner than my long-winded function?